# Run-time error '1004' when I try to put value in

Tags: excel, vba

When I try to replace the `"A3"` with `DES` ( `DES = rng.Cells(3, 1)`) inside  `.Range(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A3"))` I get run-time error 1004 and I don't know why.

The value of cell A3 in Sheet1 is B2.

Would anyone be so kind enough to explain why or what I'm doing wrong?
Below you can also find the complete script.

```
Sub ImportTBL()
    
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim QT As QueryTable
    Dim destCell As Range
    Dim qtResultRange As Range
    Dim TBL As String
    Dim URL As String
    Dim DES As String
    Dim COL As String
    
    Set sourceSheet = Sheet5
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Application.Range("Sheet1!A1")
    Dim cel As Range
        
        For Each cel In rng.Cells
            TBL = rng.Cells(1, 1)
            URL = rng.Cells(2, 1)
            DES = rng.Cells(3, 1)
            COL = rng.Cells(4, 1)
        Next cel
         
    With sourceSheet
        Set destCell = .Range(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A3"))
        On Error Resume Next
        .ListObjects(TBL).Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    
    Set QT = destCell.Worksheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & URL, Destination:=destCell)
    
    With QT
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .WebFormatting = xlNone
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebTables = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A4")
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        .Refresh
        Set qtResultRange = .ResultRange
        .Delete
    End With
    
    With destCell
        .Worksheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, .CurrentRegion, , xlYes).Name = TBL
        sourceSheet.ListObjects(TBL).ShowAutoFilterDropDown = False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: How are you using it?

Comment: @SJR How do you mean? Don't understand your question. In stead of using `.Range(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A3"))` I want to use `.Range(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(DES))`

Comment: `Des` is assigned the value of the string in A3? Does this equate to a cell reference? Perhaps `.Range(DES)`.

Comment: @JSR The value that `DES = rng.Cells(3, 1)`gives is the same as A3. Put as this script is part of a bigger script I don't want to point to cell A3 by just using `.Range(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A3"))`. In the next LOOP DES will be `DES = rng.Cells(3, 2)` so A3 will become B3

Comment: In that case I don't understand why you are wrapping it in `range`. For that to work the value of DES must be a cell reference.

Comment: Oh dear, I found it. I have to replace `.Range(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A3"))`with  `.Range(DES)`. Thank you anyway SJR

Comment: Which was my earlier suggestion ,,,